# Xbox 360 anti-dust cover

Tags: xbox-360

I plan to create my own Xbox anti-dust cover that I can easily remove every time I play. I intend to use a canvas/wool bag and cut it to be placed on top of the Xbox (shaped to cover the holes). However, I'm worried that the material could emit damaging static charges.

What would be the safest material to use?

Comment: I just use a tea towel :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try an antistatic dust cover which are commonly used on monitors.

[Here is an example I am referring to,](http://www.cwc-group.com/ducoformo17.html) and its only $2!  Just make sure the dimensions of the cover are bigger than your Xbox 360.

Also remember to remove the cover before turning the Xbox 360 back on!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Fabric-wise, I'd say avoid wool and synthetics, since these tend to create more static electricity than other fabrics.

However, almost all consumer electronics are tested to ensure they can withstand static discharge on their cases - otherwise, the first person who ran their feet across the carpet and touched the power button would short the device out.  For this reason, I wouldn't be terribly concerned with the danger of doing static damage to the exterior of an electronic device.